# Ignore case in Fiware queries

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

How I can ignore case, by doing query in Fiware Context Broker.

For example I have a query like:

v2/entities/?options=keyValues&type=Room&q=name==xyz

But this query doesn't return all the Rooms which names includes Xyz,XYZ,XyZ etc. It returns only names=xyz.

Could you please advice me, how we can do ignore case here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can only do that by using a RegExp with the operator ~=

Comment: I tried this option with my knowledge, but not working. Could you give a sample?

Comment: Which exact regex are you exactly using with the `~=` operator you say is not working? Please upgrade your question post with that information. Thanks!